# Show that $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is a $\sigma$-ideal.

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measurable space. Show that
> >     $$
> > \mathcal{N}_{\mu}:=\left\{N\subset\Omega : \exists M\in\mathcal{A}, N\subset M, \mu(M)=0\right\}
> > $$
> >     is a $\sigma$-ideal.

Hello, three things are to show:
$$
(i)~\emptyset\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu},~~~~~(ii)~N\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}, B\subset N\Rightarrow B\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu},~~~~~(iii)~(N_n)_n\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}^{\mathbb{N}}\Rightarrow\bigcup_n N_n\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}
$$

Not that difficult to my opinion:

(i):

It is $\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}, \mu(\emptyset)=0$ and therefore with $\emptyset\subset\emptyset$ it already follows that $\emptyset\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$.

(ii):

Consider $N\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}, B\subset N$. Then there exists a $M\in\mathcal{A}$ so that $N\subset M, \mu(M)=0$. Then $B\subset M, \mu(M)=0$ and that shows that $B\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$.

(iii):

Consider $(N_n)_n\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then for all $N_n,n\geq 1$ there exists a $M_n\in\mathcal{A}$ with $N_n\subset M_n, \mu(M_n)=0$. It follows
$$
\bigcup_{n\geq 1}N_n\subset\bigcup_{n\geq 1}M_m
$$
and with the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ it follows
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}M_n)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(M_n)=0.
$$
So it is shown that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}N_n\in\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$.

That's it, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. However, replace the $=$ by $\leq $ when you use the $\sigma$-additivity. The $M_n$'s are not necessarily disjoint.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I have to use $\sigma$-sub-additivity here.